# Add contentDescription for custom tabList view

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, inheritance

I have custom view of scrollable header with tabs (4 items). I want to add contentDesciption for that like it is with CheckBox, phone automatically recognizes when checkBox is selected and says "Selected" or "Unselected"

Is it possible to implement it on custom view? I tried to inherit from Checkable() and override setChecked(), isChecked() functions but it doesn't work.

```
class ProductTabs @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
{}
```

I tried to use AccessibilityDelegate

```
   binding.tabLabels.setAccessibilityDelegate(object : AccessibilityDelegate() {
                override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(
                    host: View,
                    info: AccessibilityNodeInfo
                ) {
                    // Let the default implementation populate the info.
                    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
                    // Set some other information.
                    info.isEnabled = host.isEnabled
                    host.contentDescription = "selected"
                }
    
                override fun sendAccessibilityEvent(host: View?, eventType: Int) {
                    super.sendAccessibilityEvent(host, eventType)
                    host?.contentDescription  = "selected"
                }
            })
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/custom-views) and [this](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/7158690?hl=en).

Comment: @Cheticamp Yup,